# Issue with Parsing User Input from JTextField

Tags: java, swing, parsing, input

Ok, here's what i got. Everything totally works, excepts whenever i go to convert it my answer label pops up 0.0, So i know it's at least parsing double from somewhere. I just don't know if it's getting the number from the input to use in the equation that sets my variable to my label.

Frame:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Prog8Frame extends JFrame {
    private JLabel icon;
    private JLabel temperLab;
    private JLabel fahr;
    private static JTextField input;
    private JButton convert;
    private JLabel answer;
    private JLabel degC;

    public Prog8Frame() {
        super( "Prog 8" );
        setLayout (new FlowLayout() );

        Icon thermometer = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("thermometer.png") );
        icon = new JLabel(thermometer);
        add(icon);

        temperLab = new JLabel( "Temperature" );
        add(temperLab);

        fahr = new JLabel( "Fahrenheit" );
        add(fahr);

        input = new JTextField(7);
        add(input);

        convert = new JButton("Convert");
        add(convert);
        convert.addActionListener( new ButtonHandler() );

        answer = new JLabel();
        add(answer);

        degC = new JLabel( "degrees Celsius" );
        add(degC);
    }
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent click) {
            String strInput = input.getText();
            double fahren = Double.parseDouble(strInput);
            double degCel = ((fahren - 32)*(5/9));
            answer.setText("" +degCel);
        }
    }
}
```

Tester:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Prog8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prog8Frame Prog8 = new Prog8Frame();
        Prog8.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Prog8.setSize(300, 300);
        Prog8.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: On completely different matter, you should explicitly convert one the numbers in (5/9) to double as ((double)5/9)

Comment: This has absolutely **nothing** to do with Eclipse, and all to do with core Java. Removing the tag and the mention in title. You might as well blame the brand of computer you're working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is following equation.

```
double degCel = ((fahren - 32)*(5/9));
```

`5/9` will return 0. Use `5.0/9`. This will result in double value.

```
double degCel = ((fahren - 32)*(5.0/9));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with `5/9` which is being converted back to `int` which basically equates back to `0`

Try changing it to ...

```
double degCel = ((fahren - 32)*(5d/9d));
```

instead.  This will cause Java to maintain the result as a `double`

Comment: Totally fixed it, Thank you so much!